# Possible to docker exec a Lightsail Container instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, command-line-interface, amazon-lightsail

I need to run some CLI scripts from inside the container.

I would usually do this with `docker exec`.

Is there a way to do this with Lightsail Containers or an equivalent way to run CLI scripts from inside the container?

Note: I am specifically referring to the Lightsail Containers service (not Lightsail VPS).

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: @doubleB Nope but I think I was able to accomplish what I want using the "launch command" field in the deployment UI in Lightsail Containers.